# Apply conditional css style sheet for html editor

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

For example,

(If) I have this 2d editor in HTML form:
[image]

and I have a css file named "filter" with code:

```
monochrome {
    filter: grayscale(var(--value, 100%)); --value:100%;
}
```

What are the methods to apply the "monochrome" filter to the editor's `Dragon` when placing it(The dragon sprite) onto the canvas?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="monochrome.css">
if (data[Blocks].id === "dragon") {
         
        *What should I write here in order to apply the css filter (only to the dragon sprite, when placing?*

}
```

Comment: That depends on what Dragon actually is - is it an HTML Image element? Is it A DIV? Is it a Canvas? Please provide a working snippet of your actual code which clearly shows the issue you're having.

Comment: An image element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is turning the CSS **monochrome** definition into a class. This is simply done by prepending a dot prior the name e.g.

```
.monochrome {
    filter: grayscale(var(--value, 100%));
}
```

Defining it this way makes it reusable by multiple HTML elements - as your Dragon might not be the only element which you want to apply the filter to.

As we have a CSS class now we can apply it to individual objects by calling either

```
theObject.classList.add("monochrome");
```

or

```
theObject.classList.remove("monochrome");
```

while add / remove as it's name implies adds or removes the CSS class given in quotes.

But how do we get a reference to `theObject`?
If you've given your HTML elements an unique id using it's id property it's quite easy:

```
document.getElementById("id")
```

Be careful though - it's something different than the **id** you've mentioned in your post.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("monochromeButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("dragon").classList.add("monochrome");
});
document.getElementById("removeButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("dragon").classList.remove("monochrome");
});
```

```css
.monochrome {
  filter: grayscale(var(--value, 100%));
}
```

```html
<button id="monochromeButton">
monochrome
</button>
<button id="removeButton">
remove filter
</button>
<br>
<img id="dragon" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/140">
```